# Can I monitor Oracle iPlanet Web Server 7 using JMX?

Tags: java, jython, jmx

Looking at the [Oracle iPlanet Web Server 7 release notes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18958_01/doc.70/e18789/feat_prev.htm#BABEAHBH), it supports JMX-based management.  Unfortunately I can't seem to find any documentation on Oracle's site or any other blogs, pages, etc. that show how to do this.  Doesn't anybody have any information on how this can be done?

We currently have a web dashboard that shows the health of multiple components of a system (application servers, DB servers, MQ servers, etc).  We're looking to also show the health of our Oracle web servers.

Any info or even suggestions on another way to check the health of Oracle iPlanet Web Server 7 would be greatly appreciated.  We're looking for a java/jython solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable monitoring for an iPlanet instance to publish stats in xml format '/stats-xml' or a '.perf' file. 
Once its enabled you can use wadm to list the instances -
1. For any instance running, parse the xml file for the required fields
2. If /stats-xml or /.perf is not available mark it as down.